# QTreeview iterating nodes

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

I use PyQt5 and the QTreeview to show an xml tree (and some of its attributes as columns) loaded from a file. This works as expected. But I'm now struggling with two things:

- The `itemChange` event. The tree node should be editable and I need to do some checks after editing. The `itemChange` is called but it is called N times when editing one node.
- Starting at the edited item I need to go up and down in the tree and check the child and parent nodes. I expected this to be simple like `getParent()` for one and a recursive `getChildren()` for the other direction. But how do I get form the `itemChange` events `QStandardItem` to the parent and child items?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.ElementTree(file='data.xml')


class MainFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)

        root_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        root_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Label', 'privilege', 'uid', 'docId'])
        self.tree.setModel(root_model)
        self.tree.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        root = tree.getroot()
        self._populateTree(root, root_model.invisibleRootItem())
        self.tree.expandAll()
        self.tree.resizeColumnToContents(0)
        self.tree.resizeColumnToContents(1)
        self.tree.resizeColumnToContents(2)
        self.move(0, 0)
        self.resize(800, 1000)
        #self.tree.itemChanged.connect(self.edit)


    def _populateTree(self, root, parent):
        child_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(root.tag)
        child_item.setData(root)

        privilege = ''
        uid = ''
        docId = ''
        privilege_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(privilege)
        uid_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(uid)
        docId_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(docId)

        parent.appendRow([child_item, privilege_item, uid_item, docId_item])
        privilege_item.model().itemChanged.connect(self.change_privilege)
        child_item.model().itemChanged.connect(self.change_privilege)

        for elem in root.getchildren():
            self._populateTree(elem, child_item)

    def change_privilege(self, item):
        print(item)
        print(item.row(), item.column())

    def check_parent(self, item):
        # get parent of item and check value
        # check_parent(...)

    def check_child(self, item):
        # get children of item and check value
        # for child in item.children():
        #     check_child(child)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question: every time you call `MainFrame._populateTree` you create a signal-slot connection between the signals `child_item.model().itemChanged` and `privilege_item.model().itemChanged` and the slot `MainFrame.change_privilege`. However, since all child items and privelege item belong to the same model (i.e. `root_model`) you are effectively creating multiple connections between the same signal and slot. This means that when any item in the model is changed, the slot is called multiple times as well. Easiest way around this is to create one connection in `__init__` or so.

To access the parent of an item you can indeed use `item.parent()`. The children of an item can be accessed one-by-one via `item.child(row, column)` where `row` is in the range `range(item.rowCount())` and `column` in the range `range(item.columnCount())`, e.g.

```
    def change_privilege(self, item):
        print(item.row(), item.column(), item.text())
        self.check_parent(item)
        self.check_child(item)


    def check_parent(self, item):
        if item.parent():
            print('Parent:', item.parent().text())
        else:
            print('No parent')

    def check_child(self, item):
        if item.hasChildren():
            print('Children:')
            for row in range(item.rowCount()):
                print('\t', row, end='')
                for col in range(item.columnCount()):
                    print('\t', item.child(row, col).text(), end='')
                print()
        else:
            print('No children')
```

Comment: As you say it, it is obvious... I add the signal to the tree and not to the item. Thank you for help!!